# How to get interfaces status with Netconf via ncclient

Tags: python, python-3.x, cisco-ios, netconf, ncclient

I am using `ncclient` to get information from a router (IOS-XR), however I am not able to get the status. I mean, If I run from the router the command "Show interfaces description" I can see the interface, status, protocol and description. I want to do the same with Netconf using `ncclient`. Anyone have any idea how to do it? I have tried with `get_config` and I can get the description but not the status(up, down,admin-down) and protocol (up, down,admin-down)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Netconf protocol distinguishes between configuration and operational data. In order to retrieve operational data like e.g. the interface status you have to use the `get` operation instead of the `get-config` operation.

According to [RFC 6241](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6241):
**get-config** is used to "Retrieve all or part of a specified configuration datastore."  (config data only)
**get** is used to "Retrieve running configuration and device state information." (config + oper data)

Whether a node stores configuration or operational data depends on how it is defined in the corresponding YANG module. A node can ether be `config false` or `config true` (default)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get interface details.

```
from ncclient import manager
from pprint import pprint
import xmltodict
import xml.dom.minidom

router = {
   'ip': '172.30.1.100',
   'port': '830',
   'username': 'test123',
   'password': 'test123'
}

m = manager.connect(host=router['ip'], port=router['port'], username=router['username'],
                    password=router['password'],device_params={'name':'iosxr'} ,hostkey_verify=False)

netconf_filter = """
<filter>
    <interfaces-state xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces"/>
</filter>

"""
running_config = m.get(netconf_filter)

print(running_config)
running_config_xml = xmltodict.parse(running_config.xml)["rpc-reply"]["data"]
print(xml.dom.minidom.parseString(str(running_config)).toprettyxml())
```